# Wildcard constructor in a collection

Tags: java, generics, libgdx, wildcard

In libgdx you can create a pool easily by using the abstract class `Pool`.
Since it is an abstract class you need to override it's methods anonymously when constructing it like this:

```
public Pool<String> pool = new Pool<String>() {
@Override
protected String newObject() {
   return new String();
}};
```

What I'm trying to do now is put a wildcard for the generic type T which extends a abstract BaseClass like this:

```
protected static Pool<? extends GameCommand> commandPool = new Pool<? extends GameCommand>() {
    @Override
    protected <T extends GameCommand> newObject() {
        return new T();
    }       
};
```

But it won't work. How can I get it?

**What kind of type will I have to insert when overriding newObject()?**

*EDIT:*
Pool references it's abstract method like this:

```
abstract public class Pool<T> {
(...)   
abstract protected T newObject (); 
(...)
}
```

Comment: Your first code itself will not compile. Did you try that?

Comment: It won't because you can't get the constructor from just giving the generic Type T. I'd use something like reflection there to get access to the constructor.

Comment: You may want to check out the [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) and [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) design patterns to start searching for alternative solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make a small change like making a factory method, it can be done fairly simply. As long as you can assure that all subclasses of GameCommand have a default constructor. (Although, you could get around that with Objenesis).

Just do the following:

```
public static <T extends GameCommand> Pool<T> createCommandPool(final Class<T> clazz) {
    return new Pool<T>() {
        @Override protected T newObject() {
            try {
                return clazz.newInstance();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e); // cause there isn't really much else you can do.
            }
        }
    };
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pool<? extends GameCommand> gcPool = createCommandPool(GameCommand.class);
    // MyCommand extends GameCommand
    Pool<? extends GameCommand> mcPool = createCommandPool(MyCommand.class);
}
```